# Content Security Policy... translate.googleapis.com?

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate, content-security-policy

I just put Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only on one of my sites, and aside from a surprising amount of malware, I'm also seeing reports from translate.googleapis.com, as well as some translation-related image from gstatic.com.

Is there any way to work around this kind of thing? Or do I need to essentially whitelist Google? I'm assuming I'd break their translation plugin if I went live with this Content-Security-Policy.

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide your Chrome version and the errors from the Dev console? On my page that uses CSP, the only violation I see when using the Translate fuctionality is the refusal to load the image https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/translate_24dp.png. I do not see any scripts being blocked. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164547 should have fixed this a long time ago.

Comment: Here is an example: http://pastebin.com/tjzp2M9i As for Chrome version, I added User-Agent recording this morning, but didn't have it for that one. Find out next time I see it. effective-directive also shows up as img-src and script-src.

Comment: The only error I see logged when I visit the page and use the Translate option (in context menu) is `[Report Only] Refused to load the image 'https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/translate_24dp.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' analytics.evolvapor.com". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: Same. It must be a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a plugin. Just ignore the reports.

You will find a ton of garbage in your reports, get used to filtering or ignoring the majority of reports.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too drastic, but you can add `img-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com` to your Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only settings. As you said, I imagine you would break the translation feature (and maybe make your site less secure) if you added it to your Content-Security-Policy settings. I've been using https://report-uri.io/home/tools to tweak these things.